# retrieve/display Multiple hyperlink from api json (React native)

Tags: android, reactjs, api, react-native

i have create a web app and api for it (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications) and i call my detail notification by passing the id (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications/33). from the api i can retreive my title,description,etc include my image which is store in my server (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/{api path}). Now i want to create hyperlink to download my file from my storage which has the same path with my image file. but the problem the json api for my attachment is like this

```
 ("attachment": "`[{\"download_link\":\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/SXMtnNb31ndgDnCWNC57.txt\",\"original_name\":\"dsadasdsa.txt\"},)
```

where is in array like my image but there is "download link". How can i retrieve the hyperlink from my array/json

Here the thing i have try:

```
let attachment = member && JSON.parse(member.attachment);
```

and then the hyperlink:

```
<Text style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + attachment[0]) } >Click here for to Download file</Text>

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  InputWithLabel
} from './UI';
import { FloatingAction } from 'react-native-floating-action';

type Props = {};
export default class ShowScreen extends Component<Props> {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle')
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      id: this.props.navigation.getParam('id'),
      member: '',
    };

    this._load = this._load.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._load();
  }

  _load() {
    let url = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications/' + this.state.id;

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
    .then((member) => {
      this.setState({member});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    let member = this.state.member;
   // let af = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/';
    console.log(member);
    console.log(member.image);
    let image = member && JSON.parse(member.image);
    let attachment = member && JSON.parse(member.attachment);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Title'}
            value={member ? member.title : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            multiline={true}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Department'}
            value={member ? member.department : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Publish'}
            value={member ? member.updated_at : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={[styles.output, {height: 600, textAlignVertical: 'top'}]}
            label={'Description'}
            value={member ? member.description : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
            multiline={true}
          />          
          <Text>
          {image && image.length && image.map(image => {
      return <Image 
            source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + image}}
            style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
            orientation={'vertical'}
          />  
   })
}
</Text>
<Text style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + attachment[0]) } >Click here for to Download file</Text>  
<Text style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL(member.link) } >Click here for More Detail</Text>   
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  output: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#000099',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
    TextStyle: {

    color: '#E91E63',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    fontSize: 30

  },
});
```

My excpecting output is to display all the hyperlink in the JSON which is call the "download_link"

Comment: If I am understanding your question right, i think you should use attachment[0].download_link instead of just attachment[0] in your Linking.openURL

Comment: G_S yes done now is retreiving but how do i retrieve all link such as attachment[0] and attachment [1]

Comment: You can use .map as you did for your images. did you give .map a try?

Comment: can you show using my code?

Comment: isnt it       attachment.map(eChattachment => {
      return      <Text style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={ ()=> Linking.openURL('http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + eChattachment.download_link   ) } >Click here for to Download file</Text>  })